# What command will ensure a Command Prompt window always stays on top/at the front?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am writing a silly little program in batch, and I want to make sure the CMD window is always at the front of any other windows that are called by the program.

Here are a few lines as an example of the program:

```
Echo Press 1 to see some pictures of some CUTE CATS.
Echo.
Echo Press 2 to NOT see some pictures of some CUTE CATS.
Pause >nul
Echo.
Echo.
Echo EVERYONE wants to see PICTURES OF CUTE CATS!!
Timeout 2 >nul
Echo.
Echo Here come the PICTURES OF CUTE CATS!!! :D :D :D
Timeout 5 >nul
START www.google.com/search?q=cats+cute+images
Timeout 5 >nul
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO OMG they are so CUTE!!!
TIMEOUT 10 >NUL
ECHO.
ECHO HOW CUTE DO YOU THINK THEY ARE?
ECHO.
SET /P Z=
```

After the program is activated the Command Window is on the top.  But, when the program starts the google search, the browser window opens and the command window is obscured.

Is there a command I can include in the batch script that will make the CMD window stay on top?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/557302 - here is a post i found on stack over flow. I would have put this in comments but i need 50 reputation! Edit - here is a more efficent method http://stackoverflow.com/a/33771115 one again im not taking credit

Comment: This helps, but a command would be better as this method requires me to anticipate when the user will bring other windows to the front.

Comment: There is no native CMD command that will do this.  But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932227/keeping-batch-console-on-the-screen-as-active-window) has an answer that may work for you.